# How to find pictures in directory with directory path

Tags: c#, graphics, directory, desktop-application

I am developing a graphic viewer where you can mark pictures inside a given directory to redirect them to another folder. This is supposed to help sorting large clunks of unorganized pictures into smaller folders.

My problem is I don't know how to get the picture's when the only information I have is the path of the Directory they are inside. I found something called [DirectorySearcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) but since I am new I do not know how to implement this in my program or if it will even help.

If you know how to implement it(should it really be useful) or any other method to achieve my goal please tell me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, your problem is in locating the picture files?

For one thing, what would you consider the picture files? I presume it's the extension you're using to recognize them. If so, then you can use the `System.IO.Directory` class to find all files with the desired extension.

This is how you can search for all .JPG files in the `C:\Pictures` directory and all its subdirectories:

```
string[] fullPaths = 
    Directory.GetFiles(
       "C:\\Pictures", "*.jpg",
       SearchOptions.AllDirectories);
```

Unfortunately, you would have to repeat the process for each file extension separately. Alternatively, you could search for all files (`*.*` pattern) and then filter out those that do not match any of the supported extensions.